# Why Google satellite tiles loading multiple times?

Tags: openlayers, angular

I am using following code for adding Google satellite tiles.

```
let OSLayer = new TileLayer({ 
   type: 'base', 
    visible: true,
    zIndex: -1,
    source: new XYZ({ 
       url: 'http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z{z}',
       projection: 'EPSG:27700',
       }),
    }); 
    this.map.addLayer(OSLayer);
```

[image]

Comment: Google uses an EPSG:3857 tile grid

Comment: @Mike Thanks for answering,  EPSG:3857 also it's same. I tried with both.

Comment: Your code does not match your screenshot image.  `lyrs=s` in the url is satellite but your screenshot is terrain (`lyrs=p`).  Whichever you use you must define it as `EPSG:3857` (which is the OpenLayers default) and if you want the output in EPSG:27700 you must specify that as the view projection amd add a proj4 definition for it https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-forked-5kijto?file=/main.js